# JQuery Dialog Show Hide effects

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to do this:

```
$('#mypopup').dialog({
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: true,
    resizable: false,
    show: {effect:'slide',duration:250},
    hide: {effect:'slide',duration:250}
});
```

then to open it ...

```
function showPopup() {
        if ($('#mypopup').length == 0) {
            $('#mypopup-div').load('mypopupurl/show.php'); 
        } else {
            //reopen the login dialog previously rendered, don't load again
            $('#mypopup').dialog('open'); 
        }
    }
```

then to close it ...

```
$('#mypopup').dialog('close');
```

My problem is, the show slide effect in the code above only works the first time, when it actually loads from .load('mypopupurl/show.php'); When I close it and re-open the popup dialog, it hits the else statement with the .dialog('open'); code, this time the slide effect does not happen. (not error, just pops up as normal, but no effect)

Is this a glitch in JQuery? Or is it by design? How do I make the effect work when it hits dialog('open')?

Comment: Put your full code, where do you create the dialog, where do you call `shoPopup`

Comment: key is show: {effect ...} in dialog doesn't work with dialog('open'). I don't think showing 500 lines of full code will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do something like
`$('#mypopup').show();` or `$('#mypopup').dialog().show();`

Comment: omg! it works. Thanks! What is the difference between .show() and ('open') anyway? apart from somehow open doesn't run the effects?

Comment: I thought I called .('close'), so I needed to call .('open') again, turns out, calling show() can also re-open the dialog, plus with effects.

Comment: No problem, I'm not sure I just saw that it had show within itself so assumed that's what you should use.

Comment: I am kind of new to Jquery. I checked their API http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog#methods it doesn't even have show() in its Methods. Only got open and close. So, I didn't even know they have it, I tried hide() against show(), and hide() doesn't exist. May I ask where you picked up this show() method?

Comment: I used it on a previous project, but only came to know it from guessing.